# How to validate REST request?

Tags: web-services, rest, dtd, xml-validation

Given this service:

```
POST /hotel HTTP/1.1

<hotel>
  <a>aaa</a>
  <b>bbb</b>
  <c>ccc</c>
</hotel>

HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED
Location: /hotel/123
```

When we process the request on the server we will validate the `hotel` XML in the request against a DTD.

Question is, as a REST best practice should the client refer to the DTD in the request (as one normally does when creating an XML doc based on a DTD)?  Or is this not required?  The DTD will be described in the API docs so the writers of the client service will be aware of the DTD validation details.

Comment: If this is new why using a DTD, why not XML Schema?

Comment: We are using an existing published DTD provided by an external organization.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You are doing a GET, but then saying you want to validate the XML on the server.  So how does the client get involved at all?  This issue as I understand it is completely orthogonal to REST.  It is just an XML validation issue.

Comment: @Darrel, I updated my poorly worded question..

Comment: @James Black XML Schema is a pretty poor standard really.  I'd pick it over DTDs, but certainly not over Relax NG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could certainly spit back a `400 Bad Request` if the request body fails a DTD check, but I wouldn't require the DTD reference to be present.  You should allow it to be omitted, and use it if it's there, but I would also fail the request if they specify the wrong DTD.  The error message should, of course, indicate what the expected DTD is.

You might want to consider skipping the strict conformance check if the DTD is omitted, since it's more the sort of thing that people want when they're setting up the software, but for performance reasons, might want to have off after they know everything is working.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, REST does not have anything to say on the contents of the POST body.

Obviously, you have to validate the XML on the server anyway, so the best you can do is recommend that the client validates the XML against the DTD before sending it, to save on time and bandwidth.  However, you really have no way to enforce it.

I think your responsibility as a service writer is to accept the request whether or not it refers to the DTD, but that is just my opinion.